# Make canvas as big as possible without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'd like to create a web page which contains a canvas object which fills the screen without creating scroll bars.

Setting the canvas width and height to $(window).height() and $(window).width() results in scroll bars.  Reducing the width by a few pixels is not reliable because the number I need to reduce by is different depending on the browser.

Is there a cross browser way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, this works for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
           function init() {
                var canvasBG = document.getElementById("test");
                var ctxBG = canvasBG.getContext("2d");

                canvasBG.style.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvasBG.style.height = window.innerHeight;
            };

            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="test" style="background:#eeeeee; 
               margin:0; padding:0; 
               position:absolute; 
               top:0; left:0">
        </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

*update:* You might also want to attached a resize listener to the page so if the user resizes the page you can reset the width/height.

Comment: You have a random underscore in "_canvasBG" which breaks your example. Otherwise it's still working in 2020 ;)

Comment: Thanks @user1596274. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

All the browsers that support the canvas element also support css fixed positioning. So do something like that:

```
#my_canvas {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, this stretches the canvas content rather than changing the area for drawing.

Comment: This just leaves the canvas the same size – doesn't even stretch it, at least not in Chrome. You can use position:fixed instead of position:absolute as in the accepted answer but the result is just the same – you still need to provide the height and width.